# SQL - sum field only for current table from joining 5 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

************** resolved, but better answer is welcome! :)  **************

i want to get sum of (sa003*sa004) from table sc000, before do that i must check the items exist on other table or not. Image (Some tables have same column format) :

[image]

i use 'IN' :

```
... WHERE s.sa002 IN (select b.b005 from b000 b where year(b.b001) = 2013 and month(b.b001) = 1)
```

but it needs a long process, so i am trying with 'LEFT JOIN' :

```
 SELECT s.sa002, Sum(s.SA003) AS qty, Sum(s.SA003*s.SA004) AS jumlah
 FROM sc000 s LEFT JOIN
 (select bs.b005 from b000 bs where year(bs.b001) = 2013 and month(bs.b001) = 1) b
   on s.sa002 = b.b005 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT ps.p005 from p000 ps where year(ps.p001) = 2013 and month(ps.p001) = 1 ) p
   on s.sa002 = p.p005 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT js.b005 from j000 js where year(js.b001) = 2013 and month(js.b001) = 1 ) j
   on s.sa002 = j.b005 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT rs.b005 from Rev00 rs where year(rs.b001) = 2013 and month(rs.b001) = 1) rv
   on s.sa002 = rv.b005 LEFt JOIN
 (SELECT es.b005 FROM R000 es where year(es.b001) = 2013 and month(es.b001) = 1) re
   on s.sa002 = re.b005
 where year(s.sa005) = 2013 and month(s.sa005) = 1
 and (b.b005 is not null or p.p005 is not null or rv.b005 is not null or j.b005 is not null or re.b005 is not null)
 GROUP BY s.sa002
```

the result is multiplied . Any help? :(

Update:
i want result like this (Code, Quantity from sc002, Qty*Price) :

[image]

^ without check other tables.

and then , with left join , the result like this :

[image]

Comment: Can you supply your table definitions, sample data, and desired output.  This is just too difficult to read and I think you're missing fields from your diagram.  Build a Fiddle (sqlfiddle.com) and that would make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: i was updating my question, and will looking for (sqlfiddle.com) thanks sgeddes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who see or trying to help on this question. :D

i already find the query!

i am using UNION to joining 5 tables, and got the answer what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

One (or some) of your joins does not link in one-to-one relationship. The easiest way to check is to remove group by and sum() statements and include some columns from your b, p, j, rv and re tables, like this:

```
SELECT s.sa002, s.SA003 AS qty, s.SA003*s.SA004 AS  jumlah, g.gName as gNames, 
 p.p005, j.b005, rv.b005, re.b005
 FROM sc000 s LEFT JOIN
 (select bs.b005 from b000 bs where year(bs.b001) = 2013 and month(bs.b001) = 1) b
   on s.sa002 = b.b005 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT ps.p005 from p000 ps where year(ps.p001) = 2013 and month(ps.p001) = 1 ) p
   on s.sa002 = p.p005 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT js.b005 from j000 js where year(js.b001) = 2013 and month(js.b001) = 1 ) j
   on s.sa002 = j.b005 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT rs.b005 from Rev00 rs where year(rs.b001) = 2013 and month(rs.b001) = 1) rv
   on s.sa002 = rv.b005 LEFt JOIN
 (SELECT es.b005 FROM R000 es where year(es.b001) = 2013 and month(es.b001) = 1) re
   on s.sa002 = re.b005
 where year(s.sa005) = 2013 and month(s.sa005) = 1
 and (b.b005 is not null or p.p005 is not null or rv.b005 is not null or j.b005 is not null or re.b005 is not null)
ORDER BY s.sa002
```

OR, even better,

```
 SELECT s.sa002, count(*)
 FROM sc000 s LEFT JOIN
 (select bs.b005 from b000 bs where year(bs.b001) = 2013 and month(bs.b001) = 1) b
   on s.sa002 = b.b005 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT ps.p005 from p000 ps where year(ps.p001) = 2013 and month(ps.p001) = 1 ) p
   on s.sa002 = p.p005 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT js.b005 from j000 js where year(js.b001) = 2013 and month(js.b001) = 1 ) j
   on s.sa002 = j.b005 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT rs.b005 from Rev00 rs where year(rs.b001) = 2013 and month(rs.b001) = 1) rv
   on s.sa002 = rv.b005 LEFt JOIN
 (SELECT es.b005 FROM R000 es where year(es.b001) = 2013 and month(es.b001) = 1) re
   on s.sa002 = re.b005
 where year(s.sa005) = 2013 and month(s.sa005) = 1
 and (b.b005 is not null or p.p005 is not null or rv.b005 is not null or j.b005 is not null or re.b005 is not null)
 GROUP BY s.sa002  
 HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: thanks for your help Cha, but that's not the answer I wanted :)